# ImproperlyConfigured at / Put 'django.contrib.admin' in your INSTALLED_APPS setting in order to use the admin application

Tags: python, django, django-admin, settings, installed-applications

I am getting a traceback identical to the one at this link, http://pastebin.com/Bq1Q0ert, whenever I run my project and visit it at any url.

I had resolved this issue previously by having the project serve at 0.0.0.0:8000, but now this seems to not be working either.

I am running django 1.4 and have under INSTALLED_APPS:

```
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'django.contrib.humanize',
'django.contrib.webdesign',
'admin_tools',
'admin_tools.theming',
'admin_tools.menu',
'admin_tools.dashboard',
'apps.pages',
'apps.news',
'south',
'translatable',
'easy_thumbnails',
'debug_toolbar',
'tinymce',
'rosetta',
'django_extensions',
'sorl.thumbnail',
'vendor.filebrowser',
'vendor.countries')..
```

UPDATE:
I have found that django.conf.settings.INSTALLED_APPS does not contain what is in settings.INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding this code to settings_local;

```
from settings import *
```

This does not cause any cyclic imports.